# How to use template string inside one way binding?

Tags: angular

do you know how to mix template string with interpolation ?
This line doesn't work.

```
<a [href]='`#/emailing/scenario/${marketing._id}`'>{{marketing.name}}</a>
```

Thanks !
PS: I know that the following statement could be rewritten differently, it is just for the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed this should work

```
[href]="'#/emailing/scenario/' + marketing._id"
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/GGt5FGwyWkFmNfvZuS0g?p=preview)**

or

```
href="#/emailing/scenario/{{marketing._id}}"
```

[**Plunker Example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/QWXOE7zlULryXVZb8MJ8?p=preview)

It would be nice having es6 string format working within template but AFAIK it is not supported yet

Comment: the second proposition doesn't work, can you remove it please ?

Comment: i get the error "Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected". Maybe it works in your example because the template is not in a separate file ?

Comment: I can simulate you this error `Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected`

Comment: Please take a look at this error https://plnkr.co/edit/gRwhZqYpY0cjbh2Ef6nZ?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you cannot use the **${}** string template syntax in the component template. If you strongly want to use that syntax for some reason, you could define a `getter` in your component as follows:

```
get url(){
   return `#/emailing/scenario/${this.marketing._id}`;
}
```

And then bind it in the template with:

```
<a [href]='url'>{{marketing.name}}</a>
```

Comment: Where does `marketing` come from? Did you mean `getUrl(marketing)`? What if it will be inside ngFor?

Comment: No, didnt meant getUrl(). Just a normal getter property which defines a calculated property. A ngFor would render this getter property useless, and in that case a gerUrl() would be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
<a href='#/emailing/scenario/{{marketing._id}}'>{{marketing.name}}</a>
```

Comment: `Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected` We can't use interpolation within property binding

Comment: Please test your solution

Comment: @yurzui yeah forgot to change [href] to href

Comment: @Faisal Yes tested now :P